# Adding new values to the same dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I want to merge the below dictionaries into one.

```
data1 = {
    'color': ['red', 'blue', 'green']
} # from 1st sku
data2 = {
    'color':[ 'red', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black']
} # from 2nd sku 
data3 = {
    'color': ['black', 'purple', 'yellow', 'pink']
} # from 3rd sku

i = 0    
dict={} # i want to create new dict with combination of all the available dict data in single dict with single key i.e(same key) with integrated values in a single list  
while i<10:   
    dict['color'] =  #how to process further
```

final output should be single key value pair, output should be:

```
>>> print dict    
{'color': ['red','blue','green','yellow','orange','black','purple','pink']}
```

Comment: `list(set(data1['color'] + data2['color']+ ...))`

Comment: So what have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: my problem is to union the color which are present in different skus and they are present in different databases... i am passing dbs in while loop and need to union all the color in single key value pair

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What code have **you written** to achieve that? If the answer is none, change that before asking a question; SO isn't a code writing or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
dicts = [data1, data2, data3]

total_dict = {}
for dict in dicts:
    key = dict.keys()[0]
    total_dict.setdefault(key, []).extend(v for v in dict[key] if v not in total_dict[key])
```

The result is:

```
total_dict = 
{'color': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black', 'purple', 'pink']}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data1 = { 'color':['red','blue','green'] } #from 1st sku
data2 = { 'color':['red','yellow','orange','black'] } #from 2nd sku 
data3 = { 'color':['black','purple','yellow','pink'] } #from 3rd sku

datas = [data1, data2, data3]
results = {} 
for data in datas:
    for key, val in data.items():
        def_val = results.get(key, []) # if key not exists, return []
        def_val = set(def_val) | set(val) # merge two sets, and return unique items
        results[key] = list(def_val)

def main():
    print(results)
    # output: {'color': ['pink', 'blue', 'orange', 'green', 'black', 'yellow', 'purple', 'red']}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think this code solves your problem, just copy it and try!